# Changing Email Address Displayed To Recipients in Gmail

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail

I want to know how can I change my email address to include one uppercase letter (such that email address is the same). For example, `xyz@gmail.com` should be displayed as `xyz@gmaIl.com`, where, 'i' has been changed to 'I'. In this case, the email address remains the same, but what is displayed to the recipients is different.

I have already explored Gmail's '*Send Mail As*' feature, but it throws up the error that I can "already send it as [email id]".

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the the casing in the value of the `From` header in your message.

Example in JavaScript and JQuery:

```
// You can get an access token at the OAuth 2.0 Playground for testing
// https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
var accessToken = 'ya29...';
// The Gmail API requires url safe Base64 
// (replace '+' with '-', and '/' with '_')
var mail = btoa([
  'From: emTHOLIN@gmail.com\r\n',
  'To: emtholin@gmail.com\r\n',
  'Subject: Subject Text\r\n\r\n',

  'This is the message text'
].join('')).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    raw: mail
  })
});
```

As you can see, this changes the displayed casing of the email:

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks! Is there a way to do it within Gmail itself? That is, from any setting or Chrome Console?

Comment: @aceBox Oh, my apologies. I thought you meant using the Gmail API. I don't know how to do it through the Gmail client, sadly.

Comment: That's ok. But the above code doesn't work if I have to capitalise the domain (that is, gmail => gMail doesn't work). Can you suggest improvements?

Comment: @aceBox That's a bummer. Then I would guess it is simply not possible, I'm afraid.